# "tar --exclude-backups" does not exclude files with tilde at end

Tags: backup, tar, gnu

If I have the following directory:

```
$ ls -a foo
.  ..  a  #a#  a~  b  b.bkp  c  .git  .hg  .svn
```

and call:

```
$ tar zcf foo-no-bkp.tar.gz --exclude-backups foo/
```

The resulting archive still has backup files (even those considered backup files according to [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/exclude.html)).

```
$ tar ztf foo-no-bkp.tar.gz 
foo/
foo/a~
foo/.svn/
foo/#a#
foo/.hg/
foo/a
foo/.git/
foo/b.bkp
foo/c
foo/b
```

I am using GNU tar 1.26 on Ubuntu 12.04. What can be wrong? Should it be considered a bug?

Comment: Add a file called `~a` and see whether it ignores that instead.

Comment: @Alex the `~a` file is included, too. Anyway, I have just seen backup files with a tilde at the end for now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is [a bug which has been fixed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/commit/?id=fa307a66), in July 2011, but probably hasn't made it to your version of tar yet.

v.1.26 is the current version, and [was released 19 months ago](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/refs/) (i.e. March 2011), but there will be some delay between the upstream patch and Ubuntu pushing out the fix. It looks like upstream haven't [released this](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/) as a bug fix yet, since the latest 1.26 download is still dated March 2011.